# Merging list of numbers in R

Tags: r, list, merge

I've a list with groups of numbers as follows:

```
myList <- list(1:5, c(1,3,4,7), 2:6, c(3,6:9), 4:8)
myList

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3 4 7
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 3 6 7 8 9
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 4 5 6 7 8
```

So we have 5 groups of numbers in `myList`. I want to merge two groups if they have at least `s%` same numbers in them. I compute similarity using the following function call:

```
get.Overlap <- function(group_A, group_B) 
 {   
   common <- length(intersect(group_A, group_B))
   minimum_length <- min(length(group_A), length(group_B))

   #formula: |A ^ B| / min{|A|, |B|}
   overlap_score <- common / minimum_length

   overlap_score       
 }
```

I have implemented `mergeList(myList, threshold_s)` using loops as follows:

```
  mergeList <- function(myList, threshold_s) 
   {
    returnList <- list()
    i <- 1
    while(i <= length(myList))
      {
       thisList <- myList[[i]]
       j <- i + 1
       while(j <= length(myList))
          {
            tempList <- myList[[j]]
            if(get.Overlap(thisList, tempList) >= threshold_s)
              {
               thisList <- union(thisList, tempList)
               myList[[j]] <- NULL
              }
            else
              {
                j <- j + 1
              }             
           }
       returnList <- c(returnList, list(thisList))
       i <- i + 1        
      }        
     returnList
    }
```

Now if I call `merge(myList, threshold_s)`, where `threshold_s` is set to 0.80 meaning 80% similarity, the output will be

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3 4 7
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 3 4 6 7 8 9
```

The complexity is comparatively high. I am looking for a fast implement of `merge(myList, threshold_s)` for a large list, say length of `myList` may be around 50,000.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't O(n^2)  equal to O(n^2/2)? ( thinking of the fact that this operation is transitive.)The usual function to use is `outer`.

Comment: Your example data only has 2 exclusive overlaps. What if some group A overlaps with two other groups B and C? Does it merge with both, or just the first? If B also overlaps with C, should there be a separate merged group for B and C? Can a group serve as a candidate for multiple merged groups?

Comment: your merge process is not clear, agree with bgoldst.

Comment: @bgoldst Thanks for your remark. I am trying to make it clear. Thanks to Colonel Beauvel as well.

Comment: @42 I am not sure about the complexity. So I re-write that part. Thank a lot anyway.